# which one is the right way for finding the normal vector to the surface

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

In wolfram website it is mentioned that if $z=f(x,y)$ then the normal vector to the surface $z$ is $[f_x(x,y) \quad f_y(x,y) \quad -1]^T$ where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively. Further, it is written that if $ax+by+cz+d=0$ then the normal vector is $[a \quad b \quad c]. $ Now if I write $ax+by+cz+d=0$ as $z=-\left(d/c+ax/c+by/c\right)$ and from this expression the normal vector turns out to be $[-a/c \quad -b/c \quad -1]$ which is not exactly $[a \quad b \quad c]$. Why we get two different answers here for normal vector?

Comment: Your difficulty stems from using the phrase “*the* normal vector” instead of “*a* normal vector.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both vectors are correct. The point to note here is that they are indeed parallel vectors, since we can write:
$$v_2=\alpha*v_1$$
where $\alpha$ in this case is equal to $-1/c$.

Since they're linearly dependent, they're both normal to the given plane.

Comment: I know that they are parallel. But suppose if we have $xy=1$ in this case  if we use the first strategy $i.e. y=1/x$ then we will get the normal vector $[-1/x^2 \quad -1]$ while if we write $xy=1$ as $xy-1=0$ then we get the normal vector as $[y \quad x]$ which is different from $[-1/x^2 -1]$? Where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: $xy=1$ doesn't represent a plane in 3D space, it is a 2D figure (a hyperbole, if you rewrite it as $y=1/x$ you can see it immediately). You cannot reapply the same reasoning that you did for the plane, because it is a completely different kind of function.

Comment: Even if it was a 3D figure, modifing it for example in this way: $z=xy-1$, it wouldn't have been a plane, since it has a nonlinear term (as a reference, see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3Dxy-1).

Comment: so because it is not a plane therefore I can not apply the same reasoning. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(x,y,z) = z-f(x,y) = 0$ instead.

Now

$$
\nabla g(x,y,z) \ \mbox{is the normal vector to the surface}\ \ z-f(x,y)=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

They both are valid normal vectors since they are multiple and then parallel , indeed

$$[a \, b \, c]=-c \cdot [-a/c \, -b/c \, -1]$$

Comment: I know that they are parallel. But suppose if we have $xy=1$ in this case  if we use the first strategy $i.e. y=1/x$ then we will get the normal vector $[-1/x^2 \quad -1]$ while if we write $xy=1$ as $xy-1=0$ then we get the normal vector as $[y \quad x]$ which is different from $[-1/x^2 -1]$? Where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: @FrankMoses if we consider $xy=1$ as a surface in 3D (it is a cylinder) it can't be expressed in the explicit form $z=f(x,y)$ but in the form $F(x,y,z)=k$ then the normal vector at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is $(F_x,F_yF_z )=(y_0,x_0,0)=(1/x_0,x_0,0)$. The same result is obtained is we consider the 2D curve $y=1/x$ indeed $f'(x_0)=-1/x_0^2$ then the normal line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $ y-y_0=(x_0^2)(x-x_0)$ that is $y=(x_0^2)x-x_0^2+y_0$ and thus the normal vector is $(1,x_0^2)$ which in 3D becomes $(1,x_0^2,0)=x_0(1/x_0,x_0,0)$.